# Store pointer to function return value

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

Assume that I have a function foo() that returns object of class A by value

```
A foo() {
    A a(...);
    return A;
}
```

Now in function bar() I store a pointer to the return value of A

```
void bar() {
    A* pA = &foo();
}
```

Will the return value go out of scope at the end of bar(), or is there any need to call a delete on pA ?

Comment: ***or is there any need to call a delete on pA*** You don't delete it. ***Will the return value go out of scope at the end of bar()*** Before that. You can't do this.

Answer (score 4):

**It's much worse than that!**

The behaviour on dereferencing `pA` in `bar` will be *undefined*. That's because `foo()` returns an anonymous temporary whose lifetime is limited to the statement at the call site.

You only **ever** call `delete` on a pointer that's attained by the result of an allocation using `new`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very clear.